# Recommended approach to combining raw PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a web app using Codeigniter as my framework of choice.  I have a 3rd party library that I am using to handle some OpenID authentication.  The library is written in raw PHP (I've tried some of the OpenID libraries written for Codeigniter but I couldn't get any of them to really work how I wanted to).

What is the recommended approach for using this raw PHP library alongside my Codeigniter files?  The library isn't all that big but I'd much prefer if there is a way I can just plug this library into my Codeigniter app because I am new to Codeigniter and I'd rather spend my time building my application then porting a library from raw PHP to Codeigniter if I don't have to.

Additional info: I have written several applications in raw PHP, but I am new to Codeigniter

Comment: CodeIgniter *is* PHP, so there's no need to port anything. You should be able to put the library in some folder and import it in your controllers/models/wherever when necessary and use it the way you'd use it in "raw PHP". Maybe you should write a wrapper model around it, or whatever else would be appropriate, but within that wrapper, just write normal PHP code using the library. I can't give you any specific hints since I don't have any experience specifically with CI.

Comment: Please follow what "**deceze**" is saying. He is absolutely correct in the approach.

Comment: Thanks!  Inside the Codeigniter folder structure, where would you recommend placing the library files?  The library I am using consists of several different config and class files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the library a class in a single file? The "Codeigniter Way" to handle this is to put it into your `application/libraries` directory. In CI call `$this->load->library('MyLibraryName');` before you use it. (There are also ways to load your library automatically - see `application/config/autoload.php`)

Answer (score 6):

```
include 'wherever/it/is.php';

$foo = new Bar;
```

Magic! :)

Comment: For me it wasn't really about forgetting.  It's just that I didn't know because I'm new to Codeigniter :)  Thanks for the knowledge!